# trying to programmatically create rightBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem

This doesn't seem to be working. What am i doing wrong?

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(showNewEventViewController)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem;
    NSLog(@"awaked");
    [rightBarButtonItem release];
}
```

Comment: Steve's comment about view did load sounds probable, I'd all try using the setter method setRightBarButtonItem if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would normally put this code in the `viewDidLoad` method rather than the `awakeFromNib` method; I'm not sure if that's where your problem lies. What does "not working" mean?

Comment: Not working means, the button is not displaying in the nav bar.

Comment: Steve is right. Load it in -viewDidLoad instead. -awakeFromNib won't get called in a view controller--only in a UIView class.

Comment: Both Steve and Matt are wrong. This code is fine in `-awakeFromNib` if and only if the VC itself is actually loaded from a nib. Matt, `-awakeFromNib` is called on every single object that's created from a nib, including VC's. Most likely the VC itself isn't in a nib, but it uses a nib, hence Sam's confusion. In this case, it should go in `-initWithNibName:bundle:`.

Answer (score 22):

my guess is, that you add the `UIBarButtonItem` to the wrong object! 
you need to add it, to the rootViewController (instead to the `UINavigationController`, as you probably did)

```
YourRootViewController *theRootController = [[YourRootViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController* navContainer = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:theRootController];

UIBarButtonItem *btnCancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(dismiss)];    
theRootController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnCancel

[navContainer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
[self presentModalViewController:navContainer animated:YES];
```

Comment: This was the big thing for me, I was trying to assign the button to the nav controller, not the rootViewController.  This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
- (void) initUI {   
   UIBarButtonItem *btnCancel = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                  target:self 
                                  action:@selector(dismiss)]autorelease];    

   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnCancel;

   //[btnCancel release]; no need to explicitly release the item

}
```

Comment: Why is there no need to release this explicitly, just out of curiosity?